# Restricting access to only the is_superuser. is_staff can still access page

Tags: python, django

What am I doing wrong? The is_staff can still access this page even if it isn't the superuser. Can you find my error here?

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from ManagerApp import models as pmod
from . import templater
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@login_required(login_url='/ManagerApp/login/')
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)

def process_request__new(request):
  q = pmod.User()
  q.first_name = 'New User!'
  q.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/ManagerApp/edit_user/' + str(q.id))

def process_request(request):
  '''Shows all users in the DB'''
  q = pmod.User.objects.get(id=request.urlparams[0])
  form = UserForm(initial={
    #'active': q.is_active,
    'superuser': q.is_superuser,
    'staff': q.is_staff,
    'firstname': q.first_name,
    'lastname': q.last_name,
    'username': q.username,
    'password': q.password,
    'email': q.email,
    'street': q.street,
    'city': q.city,
    'state': q.state,
    'zipCode': q.zipcode,
    'phone': q.phone,
  })
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      #q.is_active = form.cleaned_data['active']
      q.is_superuser = form.cleaned_data['superuser']
      q.is_staff = form.cleaned_data['staff']
      q.first_name = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
      q.last_name = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
      q.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
      q.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
      q.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
      q.street = form.cleaned_data['street']
      q.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
      q.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
      q.zipcode = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']
      q.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
      q.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/ManagerApp/users/')

  # return the template html
  template_vars = {
    'form': form,
  }
  return templater.render_to_response(request, 'edit_user.html', template_vars)

class UserForm(forms.Form):
  '''The question form'''
  #active = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
  superuser = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
  staff = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
  firstname = forms.CharField(required=False)
  lastname = forms.CharField(required=False)
  username = forms.CharField(required=False)
  password = forms.CharField(required=False)
  email = forms.CharField(required=False)
  street = forms.CharField(required=False)
  city = forms.CharField(required=False)
  state = forms.CharField(required=False)
  zipcode = forms.CharField(required=False)
  phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

I looked up a bunch of tutorials, but still can't find the solution to properly restrict access to only the superuser.

Also, on the edit_user page I have everyone indexed by their ID. so the URL will look like this: ManagerApp/edit_user/1/ (the # corresponds with the customer ID)

Comment: Which page? You have two views here. I presume the decorator is supposed to be associated with the first one, although it's hard to tell.

Comment: It is the edit_user page that isn't recognizing the is_superuser. I can add a user and it works great

Comment: That's not very helpful. You have two views there, `process_request__new` and `process_request`. Which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Decorators apply to a single function. Your `user_passes_test` decorator is associated with the `process_request__new` function, not the `process_request` one.

Comment: So you are saying that I need to place the decorator infront of each function I want it to effect? If it is this easy, I will +1 you

Comment: Ok, great that works! Now how do I get it to redirect to another web page instead of going to a 404 page not found

Comment: Or should I open another question?